# Ternary conditions inside the React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I figure out what is the problem with the `true/false` condition in the `handleToggleClick()` method...

When the button once clicked, the second click it does not want to recorgonize (still `false` state in the variable prop `showWarning`).

```
function WarningBanner(props) {
  if (!props.warn) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div className="warning">
      Warning!
    </div>
  );
}

class Page extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {showWarning: true};
    this.handleToggleClick = this.handleToggleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleToggleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      showWarning: true ? false : true // this is where I have a problem.
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <WarningBanner warn={this.state.showWarning} />
        <button onClick={this.handleToggleClick}>
          {this.state.showWarning ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Page />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 true ? false : true
```

Thats always `false` as `true` is always truthy and the ternary always enters the first expression. You may want:

```
 showWarning: !showWarning
```

Or if you really need the ternary:

```
 showWarning: showWarning ? false : true
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! Now I understand it